# Calculating Sentinel derived NDVI within a Polygon and exporting to a CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

This question uses code based off @Kel Markert https://code.earthengine.google.com/349615d7802d59f677181bef0badad9f

I am attempting to get a maximum monthly NDVI value from 6 small polygons over a number of years from Sentinel 2 in Google Earth Engine and export to CSV. The main difference between my code and his is the use of Sentinel 2 data instead of landsat. When I run my exact code with landsat image collection instead of Sentinel it works, but I cannot figure out why.

When I run it with the Sentinel 2 data I get the error

> "FeatureCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=00000000000000000001):
> Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: NDVI."

This leads me to believe that there must be a problem with my band names, but when I inspect them after selecting out only the NDVI band into var NDVI_only, there is only 1 band named "NDVI" just like I would expect...

Link to [my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/21c4fe67afaa84aabdc36ba959e97706)

Link to [my feature class](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/marshallthewolf/valley_bottoms)

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("users/marshallthewolf/valley_bottoms");
print(geometry);

Map.centerObject(geometry);

// Filter by Geo and Growing days
var S2_SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
            .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2020-10-01') //first BDA year
            .filterBounds(geometry) // filter to ROI
            .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)}) //iterate and clips roi over whole collection
            .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',"less_than", 25); 
// Add NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
// Apply across whole collection 
var S2_NDVI = S2_SR.map(addNDVI);

// Select out only NDVI band
var NDVI_only = ee.ImageCollection(S2_NDVI.select(["NDVI"], ["NDVI"]));
print(NDVI_only)

// Update table and export -----------------------------------------------//
var startDate = ee.Date('2018-05-01'); // set analysis start time
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-10-01'); // set analysis end time

var bandName = ee.Image(NDVI_only.first()).bandNames().get(0);
print(bandName)

// calculate the number of months to process
var nMonths = ee.Number(endDate.difference(startDate,'month')).round();

// get a list of time strings to pass into a dictionary later on
var monList = ee.List(ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n){
  return startDate.advance(n,'month').format('YYYMMdd');
}))
print(monList)

var result = geometry.map(function(feature){
  // map over each month
  var timeSeries = ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n){
    // calculate the offset from startDate
    var ini = startDate.advance(n,'month');
    // advance just one month
    var end = ini.advance(1,'month');
    // filter and reduce
    var data = NDVI_only.filterDate(ini,end).mean().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 1000
    });
    // get the value and check that it has data
    var val = ee.Number(data.get(bandName));
    val = ee.Number(ee.Algorithms.If(val,val,-999));
    // return zonal mean
    return val;
  });
  // create new dictionary with date strings and values
  var timeDict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(monList,ee.List(timeSeries));
  // return feature with a timeseries property and results
  return feature.set(timeDict);
});

// print to see if it is doing what we expect...
print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs as a result of no images being present for the time span and cloud cover filter. You can check how much images are present for each month using for example:

```
  var numbOfImages = ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n){
    var ini = startDate.advance(n,'month');
    var end = ini.advance(1,'month');
    return NDVI_only.filterDate(ini,end).size();
  });
```

You will see that there are multiple date ranges without imagery present. You could choose to extent your time span and cloud cover filter. However, noting the `ee.Algorithms.If()` within your code, you are possibly trying to assign a non-valid value to missing images. An idea to to that would be:

```
var timeSeries = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List.sequence(0,nMonths).map(function (n){
  // calculate the offset from startDate
  var ini = startDate.advance(n,'month');
  var end = ini.advance(1,'month');

  // check if there are images in time span
  var image = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If({
    condition: NDVI_only.filterDate(ini,end).size().gte(1), 
          // the valid NDVI image
    trueCase: NDVI_only.filterDate(ini,end).mean(), 
          // make a constant non-valid NDVI value image
    falseCase: ee.Image(-999).rename(bandName) 
  }));
  
  // filter and reduce (returns featureCollection)
  var data = image.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    collection: geometry,
    scale: 1000
  })
    // add the date of the image to each feature
    .map(function(feat){
      return feat.set('system:time_start', ini.millis(),
                      'system:time_end', end.millis(),
                      'numbImages', NDVI_only.filterDate(ini,end).size(),
                      'YYYMMdd', ini.format('YYYMMdd'));
    });
    
  return data;
})).flatten();
```

I would advice using `reduceRegions` for reducing multiple geometries in once. See also some other suggestion in [your code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/da0a383a41cf0be17017115260024de1).